# spsample: Error in .local(x, n, type, ...) : iteration did not converge; try enlarging argument iter

Tags: r, r-sp

I am running into this error when running random point generation over a loop. spsample works fine if I generate points just once, but if I try this repeatedly I end up (sooner or later) with this error. Any ideas how to solve it properly (I mean theoretically I could just skip the faulty iteration but this is not nice coding, right?). This problem seems to happen only with the "random" option.

```
data(meuse.riv)
meuse.sr = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(meuse.riv)), "x")))
#works fine if run just once

n<-10
points<-spsample(meuse.sr, n, "random")

for (i in 1:5000){
  print(i)
  points<-spsample(meuse.sr, n, "random")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should follow the advice of the error message:

```
for (i in 1:5000){
  print(i)
  points<-spsample(meuse.sr, n, "random", iter=10)
}
```

ran through all 5000 iterations without an error message. `?spsample` says

> iter(default = 4) number of times to try to place sample points in a polygon before giving up and returning NULL - this may occur when trying to hit a small and awkwardly shaped polygon in a large bounding box with a small number of points.

So giving it more chances can solve the problem.